# Closed: I want to return list of ids in my aggregate query, i am new to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am using below aggregate query to get the list of restaurant matches keyword search "chinese" within the list of ids passed,

```
db.business.aggregate([  
   {  
      $match:{  
         $text:{  
            $search:"chinese"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $match:{  
         "_id":{  
            $in:[  
               ObjectId("571453a82ece1392240f7b91"),
               ObjectId("5714537b2ece1392240f7b8c"),
               ObjectId("5714539a2ece1392240f7b8e"),
               ObjectId("571453962ece1392240f7b8d")
            ]
         }
      }
   },

])
```

Below is the sample data in mongodb.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("571453b32ece1392240f7b93"),
    "_class" : "com.halal.sa.data.entities.Business",
    "name" : "Chillies",
    "description" : "nice restaurant",
    "cuisine" : [ 
        "veg-nonveg", 
        "chinese", 
        "kabab"
    ],
    "address" : {
        "streetAddress" : "1000 bentley road",
        "city" : "marietta",
        "pincode" : 30067,
        "landmark" : "near delk road",
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                -84.4774305, 
                33.9202151
            ]
        }
    },
    "phone" : 123,
    "email" : "my@email.com",
    "ownerEmail" : "test@email",
    "status" : "2",
    "website" : "test.com",
    "authenticity" : "1"
}
```

please let me know the exact modified aggregate query which will only return list of _ids instead of returning all the documents from the collection. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The way I see to have really only an array of ids (like you do with distinct in find), would be by using $group

```js
  db.business.aggregate([
    { $match: { $text: { $search:"chinese" } } },
    {
      $match: {  
        "_id": {  
          $in: [  
            ObjectId("571453a82ece1392240f7b91"),
            ObjectId("5714537b2ece1392240f7b8c"),
            ObjectId("5714539a2ece1392240f7b8e"),
            ObjectId("571453962ece1392240f7b8d")
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    { $group: { _id: null, ids: { $push: "$$ROOT._id" } } }
  ]);
```

The result would give you basically something like

```js
  [
    {
      _id: null,
      ids: [/* Your ids */],
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it just used the $project in the query, thats it :-)

```
db.business.aggregate([   
    { $match: { $text: { $search: "chinese" } } },
   { $match: { "_id": {$in : [ObjectId("571453a82ece1392240f7b91"), ObjectId("5714537b2ece1392240f7b8c"),ObjectId("5714539a2ece1392240f7b8e"),ObjectId("571453962ece1392240f7b8d")]} } },       
   {$project: {"_id": "$_id"}}
])
```